# Deleting entire row based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble on figuring out how to delete an entire row if a cell in that row is equal to ).

This is what I have written, any ideas on how to make it work?

```
Dim rng As Range, rrng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:E1")
    Set rng = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
    For Each rrng In rng
    If rrng.Value = 0 Then .EntireRow.Delete
Next rrng
```

Comment: is this a follow up of your previous question where you turned all blanks to zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some minor modifications to your code, and I think it now does what you want it to do.

```
Dim rng As Range, rrng As Range
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:E1")
Set rng = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
For Each rrng In rng
If rrng.Value = 0 Then Sheet1.Rows(rrng.Row).Delete
Next rrng
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. It sums up all values in row and deletes it when the sum is 0.

```
Sub deleting_empty_rows()

Dim rng, rrng, rcell As Range
Dim i, j As Long

Set rng = Range("A1:E1")
Set rng = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))

For j = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

    Set rrng = rng.Rows(j)

    i = 0

    For Each rcell In rrng.Cells
        i = i + rcell.Value
    Next rcell

    If i = 0 Then rrng.EntireRow.Delete

Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete empty rows, use reverse loop...

Example

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Row&, i&

    i = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For Row = i To 1 Step -1
        Debug.Print Row ' Immediate Window
        If Application.CountA(Rows(Row)) = 0 Then
            i = i - 1

            If IsEmpty(Cells(Row, 1)) Then
                Rows(Row).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```